# Set column priority for sphinx search

Tags: mysql, search, sphinx

How can I set column priority for sphinx search?
for example I have title and content in my table, I would like to sort relevance first from title, and than from content.

```
sql_query               = SELECT id, content, title, alt_name FROM posts 
WHERE approve='1' AND id <=( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$cl->setFieldWeights(array('title'=>10,'content'=>5));
```

change the exact weights to taste.

Comment: Not much has changed. Played with priority numbers but result showsup the same